# Перебрасывает в самый верх страницы при событии на кнопке

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Сверстал фильтр, у него скрипт (скрипт внизу) спойлера по клику на стрелку через slideToggle в jq. Проблема следующая, при нажатии и выполнении события этого самого спойлера происходит переброска в самый верх страницы. Подскажите как можно исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$(function () {
    $('.filter__section-hide').click(function (event) {
        $(this).toggleClass('active').parent().next().slideToggle(300);
    });
});
```

Comment: Покажите полный код

Comment: @NDMX https://codepen.io/kardamon_mchl/pen/MWVrKJw

Comment: такой проблемы не наблюдаю

Comment: у вас там наверное вместо кнопки ссылка с href=#, вот и перебрасывает наверх